# Upload a large file to google drive using java api client library

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, drive

In my java code I upload a file using google drive api library, when I put a large file I get sometimes error 504:
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 504 Connection Timed Out PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Connection Timed Out

## Connection Timed Out

---

**Description: Connection Timed Out**

---

I try to solve its using this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors

but its didn’t work for me, I set a unlimited timeout and I keep getting this message.

```
public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest)
        throws IOException {
    cred.initialize(httpRequest);
    httpRequest.setWriteTimeout(minutes);
    httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(minutes);
    httpRequest.setReadTimeout(minutes);
}
```